# Clickable column in b-table doesn't register sort icon on first click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, bootstrap-vue

Still kind of new with Vue and Vuex. Using Vue 2.0 and bootstrap-vue  component. Server-side rendering so the API returns items sorted and paginated correctly. I've set no-local-sorting on the b-table.

Sorry about the length. Hard to describe. I've created a component with the table and passing in props, one of which is the Fields array, coming from the parent component. In the b-table child component, I'm defining one of these fields as clickable by inserting into the #cell slot and including a b-link tag. Here is the code where I'm inserting into the #cell slot within the child:

```
            <!-- Edit button (key field called 'action' in fields array) -->
            <template #cell(action)="row">
              <b-link
                size="sm"
                @click="showItemDetail(row.item, row.index, $event.target)"
              >
                <!-- Edit -->
                {{ row.item[keyField] }}
              </b-link>
            </template>
```

I'm using "action" in the #cell() to match the field definition key being passed into the child component through props that I want to click on to open the item detail view. Here is the fields array being passed in:

```
      fields: [
        {
          key: "action",
          label: "Batch Id",
          sortable: true,
          sortBy: "batchId",
        }, ...
```

Note that the key "action" is the same as the #cell(action) in the b-table child component. With this, the batch id column shows up as a link and when I click it, showItemDetail is fired and the item view is displayed. Works. The table is displayed with another column as the initial sort.

PROBLEM: When I click on the batch id (action column) column header to sort the first time, the server correctly returns and the table displays data sorted by batch id but the sort indicator is not updated and doesn't show the up arrow (ascending). Doesn't show any indication of sort except for the actual order of the data. I can see the background data being sent with the correct sort order and sort direction, obviously, since the server knows what to return.

When I click the second time, it sorts it ascending again (probably because it thinks it's not sorted by that column yet) and the ascending up arrow is highlighted. Clicking again, sorts by descending and correctly shows the down arrow. So, it's only the first time that the arrow doesn't light up and that it doesn't recognize that it's been sorted.

[image]

Thanks for reading through this. It's very possible I'm going about this wrong and there's a better way of abstracting out code, clicking on a row to show the detail, with server-side rendering. All a bit overwhelming to me right now and I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem but I couldn't. Can you please share a jsfiddle or something for a better understanding of the issue?

Comment: Yea, it's a bit involved and I really appreciate you giving it a go. See below at the fix I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of hack, but this is how I managed to fix this problem, in case it will help someone else:

1. Added the following v-bind to b-table:

```
   @sort-changed="onSortChanged"
```

2. Added class property to the "action" field in the fields array (just so I can easily find it using querySelectorAll.
3. And added this method:

```
        async onSortChanged(ctx) {
      //Sort changed on Action colulmn:
      // Fix issue where sort indicator doesn't show ascending
      // the first time we click on the action column sort
      if (this.fixSortFlag) return;
      if (ctx.sortBy === "action") {
        this.fixSortFlag = true;
        try {
          const el = document.querySelectorAll(".colAction");
          const attr = el[0]?.getAttribute("aria-sort");

          if (ctx.sortDesc === false && attr !== "ascending") {
            // Set sort indicator up
            el[0].setAttribute("aria-sort", "ascending");
            // this.sortOrder = false;
          } else if (attr === "ascending") {
            // Set sort indicator down
            this.sortOrder = true;
            el[0].setAttribute("aria-sort", "descending");
          }
        } finally {
          this.fixSortFlag = false;
        }
      }
    },
```